# Rewarding users for being kind/helpful

Tags: discussion, welcoming

This is expanding off the recent discussions over Stack Overflow users being notoriously unfriendly - Occasionally I'll see a bad question from a new user, but instead of a commenter down-voting or lashing out, they welcome the user to Stack Overflow and politely explain why they should edit or change their question.

We have an option to flag comments as rude or abusive, but in a situation like this I just *wish* I could flag it as kind or helpful, and maybe this could contribute towards a badge reward for the commenter.

Maybe my idea is far-fetched, but it could help combat the "unwelcoming environment" atmosphere that Stack Overflow can be sometimes. Has this idea ever been explored? **How do we reward our users for being kind/helpful?**

Comment: Downvoting and leaving a helpful / welcoming comment should not be mutually exclusive IMO. Poor quality questions should still be downvoted. Lashing out on the other hand isn't useful.

Comment: @James_Parsons You're right, I didn't mean to phrase it like that. I meant to pair downvoting + lashing out as the opposite of writing a helpful comment, however I don't think they have to leave an upvote with the helpful comment.

Comment: I'm always kind and helpful. Where is my reward?

Comment: _"they welcome the user to Stack Overflow and politely explain why they should edit or change their question"_ And yet so many users (not necessarily new ones) feel offended by those comments anyway. Would this be a reward or a consolation prize for taking the risk of facing exaggeratedly defensive behaviours?

Comment: I don't see why overcomplicating ... so you suggest to have 3 categories, bad comment, normal comment, good comment ? ... It's easy as it's now: When adding a comment it should be something helpful, if not we flag it.

Comment: @rene That's the spirit!

Comment: @E_net4 I disagree - what's drawing you to think that? A well written comment can save the user from feeling stupid or embarassed.

Comment: KIND but STRICT users are rewarded by having a clean and useful Q&A web site

Comment: @dwirony I am drawn to think this from *personal experience*. Regardless of how good the comment might be, there's a risk of it being translated to the extreme opposite.

Comment: @dwirony If you actually look at the people complaining about the site, and the comments they point to as being problematic, you almost universally see polite and professional comments by people explaining why a post is problematic and how it could be improved.  You basically never see anything that is insulting, rude, or unprofessional.

Comment: @dwirony "I meant to pair downvoting + lashing out as the opposite of writing a helpful comment" -- "instead of a commenter down-voting *or* lashing out [...]" (emphasis mine) comes across as suggesting that both actions, in isolation, are problematic. I suggest reprhasing that as "instead of a commenter lashing out [...]", as the allusion to downvotes appears to be a distraction from your main point.

Answer (score 13):

We already have such a feature. If you hover over the helpful comment, you can click the upvote arrow that appears to the left.

There is already a badge, [*Pundit*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/94/pundit), with criteria of "Leave 10 comments with score of 5 or more".

Comment: Fair point - and thank you for pointing out that that badge exists, I had never seen it before. However, I still feel like that is inadequate incentive for users to be kind or helpful.

Comment: Yes sir, my typo.

Comment: @dwirony Part of the problem lies in how to make sure people use a "kind and helpful" flag to flag comments that actually are kind and helpful. If that did not happen, the flag would become merely a second, redundant way of upvoting a comment. With things like close votes, the review queues play a moderation-of-moderation role that helps keeping things on track; however, having a review queue for comments is pretty much unthinkable.

Comment: @duplode are you saying that we should have separate "useful" and "helpful" upvotes? E.g. a comment could be helpful but not useful, useful but not helpful, both helpful and useful, or neither helpful nor useful? Can you provide examples of each of those categories?

Comment: @RobertColumbia Not really. I just meant that even if we hypothetically managed to come up with a distinction of this sort there would be no sensible way to ensure people would consistently use it when choosing which of the two upvote to cast. (In other words, I agree with your answer.)

Comment: @duplode yes, I think we could possibly come up with a definition that defined "helpful" in an *interpersonal* way and "useful" in a technical or site-maintenance way, but most of the best comments fulfill both at the same time (and the worst fulfill neither) and administering that kind of system and educating users would be really difficult as you mention.